# @RequestHeader Map<String, String> is not working in swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

I have a controller with method @GET. I would like to pass headers as a Map<String, String>, but a field to pass headers is not visible on swagger UI side.

For example: When I tried to pass header as a @RequestHeader String something - field is visible on swagger UI part, just above place to pass body, but after annotation there is a Map, there is no place to put this headers at all.

```
public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getObject(
            @RequestHeader String test,
            @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {

//logic here
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyBQW.png)

I would like to be able to pass for example three headers via some textbox (like @RequestBody is working). Not to create countless amount of labels with concrete headers, I would like to pass headers through map via swagger UI. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing data via request headers like this. Request headers are used to pass information about the client to the server (eg does the client accept gzipped responses)

To pass data to the server you should either use:

- Request parameters (@RequestParam)
- Path Variables (@PathVariable)
- The body of a POST (@RequestBody)

**Note that GET requests do not support a @RequestBody** (standard HTTP protocol, nothing to do with spring / swagger)

Here's an example POST with @PathVariable, @RequestParam and @RequestBody

```java
public class MyBodyBean {
   private String value1;
   private String value2;
   private String value3;

   // getters / setters
}
```

```java
public class FooController {
   @PostMapping("/foo/{test1}/do-something/")
   public ResponseEntity doSomething(
      @PathVariable("test1") test1,
      @RequestParam("test2") test2,
      @RequestBody MyBodyBean body
   ) {
      doStuff(test1, test2, body);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

To invoke this you would POST a JSON body to `/foo/xxx/do-something?test2=yyy`

The JSON body would look something like

```json
{ 
  "value1":"A", 
  "value2":"B", 
  "value3":"C" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a response. Actually good point, but it is not my choice to pass it like this. What I find - when you are passing RequestHeader as a custom object, map inside of this object is visible and I can pass object to swagger, but just map I can't. It is possible to be able to pass a map of strings?

Comment: You could pass as a request parameter but note that this would need to be URL encoded. So `{"foo":"bar"}` would become `%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%7D`. Eg /myapp/someurl?map=%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%7D. It's possible that the swagger UI would do the URL encoding for you